# Can we use mvn build command through command line

Tags: eclipse, maven, command-line

I'm trying to use `mvn build` command for a Maven project to generate a `tar` file.

When I run my Maven project in Eclipse through *Run as* → *Maven build*, Eclipse can generate a `tar` file. But, the problem is when I used `mvn build` in command line, it says that unable to execute since `mvn build` is not a life cycle. So, can anyone say can we use `mvn build` through command line? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with: mvn install

Comment: @JoachimRohde I actually did it with mvn install. but i was asked to do that  using mvn build. I searched rigorously in google but didn't found any answer. That's why i asked here to know whether mvn build can be used or not?

Comment: If you are using "mvn install" 'install' is the goal that is called. The lifecycle that belongs to 'install' is "build" (see also https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) Maybe a misunderstanding? I'm not aware of a goal named 'build' from the standard set.

Comment: @JoachimRohde Thank you for the solution.

Comment: It seems you are confused about the option "Maven Build" that you see in Eclipse. It does not run the command `mvn build` at all. I answered a question about the difference recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999457/what-is-the-difference-between-maven-install-and-maven-build-with-m2eclipse

Comment: @Tunaki. It helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one of [Maven's built-in lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) you have to invoke it with `mvn <phase>` inside your project's directory (where the POM [`pom.xml`] is located) on the command line. (And, as already commented, there is no phase called "build".)

*Maven build* is only available as a menu item of the [M2Eclipse (m2e) plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) in Eclipse.

Comment: `mvn<phase>` in the sense `mvn test` or `mvn install` like this right?

Comment: @krishnapatamsetti Yes, depending on what you would like to achieve. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) for how lifecycles, phases, etc. work together.